# How can I write this SQL query to LINQ?

Tags: sql, linq

This is the query:

```
   select * from Product
   inner join Restaurant on Product.RestaurantId=Restaurant.RestaurantId 
   where Product.ProductName like '%something%' and Restaurant.RestaurantAddress 
   like '%something%'
```

Comment: Search for how to join lists using LINQ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can as the below:

```
 var result = (from p in db.Product
              join r in db.Restaurant on p.RestaurantId equals r.RestaurantId
              where
                    p.ProductName.Contains("something") &&
                    r.RestaurantAddress.Contains("something")
              select new
              {
                    Product = p,
                    Restaurant = r
              }).ToList();
```